# Are there any analysis textbooks like Charles Pinter's A book of abstract algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, self-learning, book-recommendation

I really like Pinter's exposition of Algebra. He breaks down each and every term and goes to extent of explaining you instead of throwing the proofs at you. This textbook is wonderful if you are a complete novice. He teaches through the exercises in the text. This is an ideal textbook for self learning.

However, I was wondering if there were any such texts on Analysis. I tried learning from Abbott's Understanding Analysis. However, he leaves most of proofs to the reader with a little to no hint.

Comment: Strichartz Way of Analysis

Answer (score 1):

I peeked at the book on amazon, and it does look great for self-study indeed! If you want to study Functional Analysis, I recommend the book by Kreyszig called *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications* - you will not be disappointed.

Comment: That's great but I was looking for real analysis textbooks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried these 3 books? Please report back, and comment below.

| Authors | Title | Publication Year | Publisher |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jonathan M. Kane | [*Writing Proofs in Analysis*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-30967-5) | 2016 | Springer |
| Raffi Grinberg | [*The Real Analysis Lifesaver: All the Tools You Need to Understand Proofs*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691172934/the-real-analysis-lifesaver) | 2017 | Princeton University Press |
| Daniel W. Cunningham | [*Real Analysis With Proof Strategies*](https://www.routledge.com/Real-Analysis-With-Proof-Strategies/Cunningham/p/book/9780367549664#) | 2021 | Routledge |